# What should I use instead of sscanf?

Tags: c++, scanf, std

I have a problem that sscanf solves (extracting things from a string). I don't like sscanf though since it's not type-safe and is old and horrible. I want to be clever and use some more modern parts of the C++ standard library. What should I use instead?

Comment: For example for the reason he said, that sscanf is not type-safe.

Comment: @Kaleb Pederson: For many English speakers, "clever" can just mean "smart" and doesn't have the negative connotation it sometimes has in the US. Note that Ben Hymers is from the UK.

Comment: "Clever" has negative connotations? That probably says something about the US. I'm not sure what though. Yes, I meant smart :)

Comment: @BenHymers Come to think of it, yes, in the US "clever" is sometimes used with a touch of irony to mean something along the lines of "creative, but naughty".  Self-modifying code is something one might call clever in this way.

Comment: Yes that's right. Discussing "clever" vs "smart" is far more important :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <sstream>

...

std::stringstream s("123 456 789");
int a, b, c;
s >> a >> b >> c;
```

Comment: how to know if c is not there, for example the string were "123 456"?

Comment: @unludo: In that case, `c` would be unmodified. You could initialize `c` with a default value, or you might need more sophisticated parsing. A tokenizer would probably work.

Comment: As of C++11, `c` would be reset to `0`, and before that I believe its post-failure value was undefined.  Anyway, to check whether `c` is there use the stream state (for convenience, from `operator bool()`): `if (s >> a >> b) if (s >> c ) abc_there(); else ab_there(); else didnt_have_a_and_b();`.

Answer (score 7):

For most jobs standard streams do the job perfectly,

```
std::string data = "AraK 22 4.0";
std::stringstream convertor(data);
std::string name;
int age;
double gpa;

convertor >> name >> age >> gpa;

if(convertor.fail() == true)
{
    // if the data string is not well-formatted do what ever you want here
}
```

If you need more powerful tools for more complex parsing, then you could consider Regex or even Spirit from Boost.

Answer (score 2):

If you include `sstream` you'll have access to the stringstream classes that provide streams for strings, which is what you need. Roguewave has some good [examples on how to use it.](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/leif/sourcepro/html/stdlibref/basic-stringstream.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want not to use streams (It's good because of readability), you can use
StringPrintf.

You can find its implementation in Folly:

https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/String.h#L165

Comment: Nice bit of code (I'm using something almost the same already), though it's a replacement for `printf` rather than `sscanf`.

Answer (score -1):

fgets or strtol