# C++ alternative for parsing input with sscanf

Tags: c++, parsing, scanf

Assuming my program expects arguments of the form `[ 0.562 , 1.4e-2 ]` (i.e. pairs of floats), how should I parse this input in C++ without regular expressions? I know there are many corner cases to consider when it comes to user input, but let's assume the given input closely matches the above format (apart from further whitespace).

In C, I could do something like `sscanf(string, "[%g , %g]", &f1, &f2);` to extract the two floating point values, which is very compact.

In C++, this is what I've come up with so far:

```
std::string s = "[ 0.562 , 1.4e-2 ]"; // example input

float f1 = 0.0f, f2 = 0.0f;

size_t leftBound = s.find('[', 0) + 1;
size_t count = s.find(']', leftBound) - leftBound;

std::istringstream ss(s.substr(leftBound, count));
string garbage;

ss >> f1 >> garbage >> f2;

if(!ss)
  std::cout << "Error while parsing" << std::endl;
```

How could I improve this code? In particular, I'm concerned with the `garbage` string, but I don't know how else to skip the `,` between the two values.

Comment: To answer your question, you can improve the code by using `sscanf()`. If you can't use sscanf(), then you should state the reason. In that case, the question has been asked many times before, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033207/what-should-i-use-instead-of-sscanf

Comment: Unfortunately C++ is more verbose than C. If you have a C++11 compiler you might want to look into [regular expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't think regexes should be recommended for parsing floating point data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The obvious approach is to create a simple manipulator and use that. For example, a manipulator using a statically provided `char` to determine if the next non-whitespace character is that character and, if so, extracts it could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <char C>
std::istream& expect(std::istream& in)
{
    if ((in >> std::ws).peek() == C) {
        in.ignore();
    }
    else {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}
```

You can then use the thus build manipulator to extract characters:

```
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    std::string s(ac == 1? "[ 0.562 , 1.4e-2 ]": av[1]);
    float f1 = 0.0f, f2 = 0.0f;

    std::istringstream in(s);
    if (in >> expect<'['> >> f1 >> expect<','> >> f2 >> expect<']'>) {
        std::cout << "read f1=" << f1 << " f2=" << f2 << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "ERROR: failed to read '" << s << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's unlikely that all your tokens will be nicely space separated like that.

Answer (score 7):

I you can afford to use boost, you could use Spirit.

See

- **From a `string` [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b94c10cfda922ec)** (in c++03):
- **Update** And here's the approach if you were actually trying to read from a stream (it's actually somewhat simpler, and integrates *really* well with your other stream reading activities): 
  **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82ea3f1a953245d2)** too (c++03)

Allthough this seems more verbose, Spirit is also a **lot** more powerful and type-safe than `sscanf`. And it operates on streams.

Also note that `inf`, `-inf`, `nan` will be handled as expected.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c4a69ecd08ccce0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <sstream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::istringstream ss("[ 0.562 , 1.4e-2 ]"); // example input
    ss.unsetf(std::ios::skipws); // we might **want** to handle whitespace in our grammar, not needed now

    float f1 = 0.0f, f2 = 0.0f;

    if (ss >> qi::phrase_match('[' >> qi::double_ >> ',' >> qi::double_ >> ']', qi::space, f1, f2))
    {
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << f1 << " and " << f2 << "\n"; // default formatting...
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Error while parsing" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know how powerful Spirit was until now. I'm going to accept Dietmar Kühl's answer, though, because I cannot use boost in this specific case. But I'll keep this in mind for later use.

Comment: Unfortunately that code doesn't work anymore. Compiler is showing an error "Use of overloaded operator '>>' is ambigous". Would you know why?

Comment: Oh also, it spits this error only when I pass f1 and f2 as arguments. Without them i.e.   

  `if (ss >> qi::phrase_match('[' >> qi::double_ >> ',' >> qi::double_ >> ']', qi::space))` there is no ambiguity error.

Comment: Added a link to demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c4a69ecd08ccce0). What's different for you @AlanKałuża?

Answer (score 2):

Other than regular expressions, there's probably something in Boost you can use. But if you can't use Boost then you can define a `std::ctype<char>` facet that effectively ignores all unnecessary characters by classifying them as whitespace. You can install this facet into a locale and imbue it into `ss`.