# Best way to Ignore an Input Character in a Stream

Tags: c++, stream, scanf, extraction-operator

Given the input: `const char input[] = "lorem\t,   ipsum"` and the expected outputs: `char first[size(input)]` and `second[size(input)]` I can do this:

```
sscanf(input, "%s , %s", first, second);
```

Ignoring white-space and the delimiting character with `,`. I'd like to do the same thing with a stream, but the best I can come up with is:

```
istringstream foo(input);

foo >> first;
foo.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ',');
foo >> second;
```

What I'm really looking for is something more like:

```
istringstream(input) >> first >> ',' >> second;
```

But obviously that's illegal. I've thought of:

1. A dummy value to extract the delimiter into
2. A regex iterator

I don't know if there's a more elegant solution, I'd certainly like something that I could do inline, similar to the `sscanf` solution.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/mEUDrV)

Comment: A dummy value seems reasonable to me.

Comment: `char eater; ...; stream >> foo >> eater >> bar` is a common occurrence in my parsing code for just this purpose.

Comment: Thanks to @NathanOliver I now have a large monster with big, googly eyes and fluffy blue fur that gobbles up characters stuck in my mind. I think I will call him `char`rie Monster and pray I'm not sued by the Children's Television Workshop.

Comment: FWIW, you could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23305012/4342498) to make the code more expressive and get some error handling.

Comment: Per NathanOliver: possible duplicate of [C++ alternative for parsing input with sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304177/c-alternative-for-parsing-input-with-sscanf)